# Transferring percentage scores to raw scores

Tags: percentage

I have a question ranging from 1 to 5. I have 10 subjects, 6 persons select 4 and 4 persons select 5, So the average question is 4.4. If I calculate percentage for response modes ( 1 to 5), I get the following result

```
1  2  3  4   5  
0  0  0 60  40
```

How I can get the values of 4.4 based on these percentages. Is that possible?
Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for..Are you asking "how do I compute an average for values in a table? Is this an exercise for some class?

Comment: @Glen- Based on the above table, how I can get 4.4 ( the average question).

Comment: How does that calculation relate to your title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For tabulated values, where you have outcomes $x_i$ with proportions $p_i$:

```
 x    0   1   2   3   4   5
 p    0   0   0   0  0.6 0.4
px    0   0   0   0  2.4 2.0
```

then the sample mean is $\sum_i p_i x_i=0+0+0+0+2.4+2.0=4.4$

This is entirely algebraically equivalent to writing out the ten scores 4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5 and averaging those